# Making a basic date(technical)

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

NO JQUERY!  I have a drop down in which the user selects a day month and year.  I create the following code and pass these values into the variable using setFullYear.  At times I also add days to this variable which is waht the variable ev_num is for.  When I write this to the page it displays a lot of unnecessary info...

Sat Jan 01 2011 11:44:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I want it to simply read 'Jan 01 2011' or something like that.  Does anyone know how I would fix this.  Here is a jsfiddle of the entire page...  http://jsfiddle.net/fET6v/

```
var myDate=new Date();
var ev_num = parseInt(document.getElementById("leave").value)
myDate.setFullYear(sel_year.value,sel_month.value,sel_day.value);
var event_value = document.getElementById("leave").value;
```

Comment: Can you please put the js code in the fiddle into the JavaScript section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct"," Nov","Dec"];
var currentMonth = months[month];
document.write(currentMonth + " " + day + " " + year);
```

This will print today's date with abbreviated months. It's fully customizable.

http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/u7hkE/

EDIT: See this demo for the leading zero in front of the day number: http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/u7hkE/1/

Comment: You forgot about the leading zero for the day value

Comment: It uses the "<" character, so I highly recommend you put the script in an external file to avoid conflicts with the HTML.

Comment: Yes, *you* should do it :-) Have you ever realized there is a [JavaScript field at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7hkE/2/)?

Comment: Yes, I have, but The original question was all in the HTML field

Comment: Good call with the leading zero.  Can you +1 me :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the time and timezone to appear, use the [`.toDateString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) instead of the simple `toString`. If you want a custom format, you will need to build the string yourself, you can get the single year/month/date values with the respective methods from your [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. There are some (googlable) libraries to do that, a single method for your case would be

```
function myDateString(date) {
    return ["Jan","Feb","Mar", …][date.getMonth()] +
           " "+("0"+date.getDate()).substr(-2) +
           " "+date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example of this??

Comment: You do use `.toString` implicitly when printing/alerting/etc a `Date` object, or when concatenating it with an other string

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format